# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, xml

Olá eu tenho um código que lê XML, porem esse XML pode ou não ter o campo `vICMSST` e  por isso eu usei um `IF` que verifica se é `None`, assim:

```
import xlrd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from itertools import chain
from copy import deepcopy
#Bibliotecas
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
tree = ET.parse(r"C:\Users\Expedição\Downloads\35200961974911000104550010000752631862357412-nfe (1).xml")
root = tree.getroot()
Contagem = 1
ns = {'nfe': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}
print("#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#")
varialvel = input("coloque o valor da bonificação aqui: ")
for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    ICMS = det.find('.//nfe:vICMS', ns).text
    IPI = det.find('.//nfe:vIPI', ns).text
    quantidade = det.find('.//nfe:qCom', ns).text
    if det.find('.//nfe:vICMSST', ns).text is not None:
        ICMSST = det.find('.//nfe:vICMSST', ns).text
    else:
        ICMSST = 0
```

O XML:

```
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<infNFe Id="NFe35200961974911000104550010000752631862357412" versao="4.00">
<ide>
...
</ide>
<emit>
...
</emit>
<dest>
...
</dest>
<det nItem="1">
<prod>
...
</prod>
<imposto>
<vTotTrib>3481.64</vTotTrib>
<ICMS>
<ICMS00>
<orig>0</orig>
<CST>00</CST>
<modBC>3</modBC>
<vBC>38857.60</vBC>
<pICMS>18.0000</pICMS>
<vICMS>6994.37</vICMS>
<vICMSST>884.54</vICMSST># CAMPO QUE PODE OU NÂO EXISTIR #
</ICMS00>
</ICMS>
```

Mas obetenho esse erro:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem mais detalhes, o problema parece estar em algumas dessas linhas:

```
ICMS = det.find('.//nfe:vICMS', ns).text
IPI = det.find('.//nfe:vIPI', ns).text
quantidade = det.find('.//nfe:qCom', ns).text
if det.find('.//nfe:vICMSST', ns).text
```

Afinal, você tenta pegar o `text` de um campo sem verificar se o mesmo existe. Se algum deles não existir, o retorno de `find` é `None`, e ao tentar pegar o `text` de `None`, dá o erro.

Uma sugestão é criar uma função genérica que obtém o valor do campo caso ele exista, e se não existir, retorna algum valor *default*:

```
def get_text(node, nome, ns, valor_default=''):
    # procura pelo campo a partir do node
    campo = node.find(nome, ns)
    if campo is None: # campo não existe, retorna o valor default
        return valor_default
    return campo.text # retorna o text do campo
```

Ou seja, ele busca pelo campo e retorna o `text`. Mas se o campo não for encontrado, retorna o valor *default* (que por padrão é a string vazia, mas você pode passar qualquer outro que desejar).

Aí bastaria fazer:

```py
for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    ICMS = get_text(det, './/nfe:vICMS', ns)
    IPI = get_text(det, './/nfe:vIPI', ns)
    quantidade = get_text(det, './/nfe:qCom', ns)
    ICMSST = get_text(det, './/nfe:vICMSST', ns, 0) # se não encontrar, usar o zero como valor default
```